# prove the result of a Laplace transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, integers, laplace-method

I have to prove the next problem

$$\mathcal{L}
 \left(\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1-e^{-u}}{u}du,s\right) = \frac{1}{s}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{s}\right)$$

I'm quite new in the subject and I have troubles with this one. There's no need to put the step by step, just the initial ones to know that I'm going in the right way 
(but if you want to,that would be great)

Thanks!

Comment: integrate by parts $\int_0^\infty e^{-st} \int_0^t \frac{1-e^{-u}}{u} du dt$, and differentiate $d/ds$

Comment: @user1952009 The point is that $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{1-e^{-u}}{u}du$ is *not* convergent.

Comment: @OlivierOloa : so what ?

Comment: @user1952009 So the integrated part doesn't converge.

Comment: @OlivierOloa : try yourself with $\int_0^a e^{-st} \int_0^t \ldots du dt$ and let $a \to \infty$ you'll see that it converges when $Re(s) > 1$

Comment: @OlivierOloa: but even function that go to $+\infty$ as $x\to +\infty$ have Laplace transforms. It is the case of $\sqrt{x}$, for instance.

Comment: I know that. But it requires some skills...

Comment: no it doesn't require some skills ! it is the definition ! really I don't get what you mean @OlivierOloa, $\int_0^\infty f(t) g'(t)dt $ is by definition $\lim_{ a\to \to \infty}\int_0^a f(t) g'(t)dt $ and integrating by parts is obviously $\lim_{ a\to \to \infty}(f(a)g(a)-f(0)g(0)- \int_0^a f'(t) g(t) dt$

Comment: @OlivierOloa: I don't agree with that. One has just to apply the definition of the Laplace transform and perform some computation. If the Laplace transform has a horrible singularity at $s=0$ does not concern us at the moment.

Comment: @user1952009 What I mean is the difficulty to find $\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{-e^{-st}}s\int_0^t(1-e^{-u})/udu$

Comment: $t$ is the variable of the function we want to trasform. So, yes, $\lim_{t \to +\infty} f(t) = +\infty$, the same applies to $f(t)=\sqrt{t}$, but $\sqrt{t}$ has a Laplace transform, it is $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 s^{3/2}}$. With a horrible singularity at $s=0$, but who cares?

Comment: @OlivierOloa : the point is that you said a mistake

Comment: @user1952009 I mean there is some difficulty to find $\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{-e^{-st}}s\int_0^t\frac{1-e^{-u}}{u}du$, since  $\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_0^t\frac{1-e^{-u}}{u}du$ doesn't exist. No?

Comment: @OlivierOloa : no because $Re(s) > 0$, that's part of the problem of computing the Laplace transform : finding the domain of convergence (what we only need is finding a $\sigma$ such that it converges for $Re(s) > \sigma$ (for the unilateral LT) and then move left $\sigma$ to find the whole domain of convergence (by searching the right-most singularity of the function, which might be very complicated in some cases, see the RIemann hypothesis))

Comment: @OlivierOloa: no, because by squeezing $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1-e^{-u}}{u}\,du$ is bounded by some multiple of $\log(t)$, so that limit is simply zero.

Comment: OK, I wanted to point out it was not so direct.

Comment: @OlivierOloa : sorry, to me it was obvious that the integral was well-defined for $Re(s)$ large enough (since otherwise the unilateral LT isn't defined). a fast check showed that there were only $\mathcal{O}(e^{C t})$ terms for some $C$ , nothing increasing faster than exponential so everything was ok

Comment: @user1952009 No problem. Sometimes what is obvious for someone, is not obvious for someone else ;)

Comment: @OlivierOloa: E. De Giorgi is remembered for saying that very often :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $\text{Re}(s)>0$ we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathcal{L}\left(\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1-e^{-u}}{u}\,du\right)&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{-st}-e^{-st-u}}{u}\,du\,dt\\(\text{Sub.}\;u=tv)\quad&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-st}-e^{-(s+v)t}}{v}\,du\,dt\\(\text{Fubini})\quad&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{v}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(e^{-st}-e^{-(s+v)t}\right)\,dt\,dv\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dv}{v}\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s+v}\right)\,dv\\&=&\frac{1}{s}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dv}{s+v}=\frac{1}{s}\left[\log(s+1)-\log(s)\right]\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{1}{s}\,\log\left(1+\frac{1}{s}\right)}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: the change of variable $u = tv$ is indeed a good idea, and so you supposed $Re(s) > 0$ for everything to converge, which is also the domain of convergence

Comment: @user1952009: good point, now added.